# Civicrm Angular Module system generated files keeps growing exponentially

Tags: civicase, mailing

Does anyone know why the angular-modules system  generated files in the contribute/dyn keeps growing at en exponential rate. Also clearing the cache doesn't seem to delete these files. We have more than 10k of those files at the moment. Any Ideas?

Comment: What version are you on because I'm wondering if this is a recent change, since I do remember clearing cache used to clear the folder, but yes now on latest master not only does clearing cache not clear them, just the act of clearing adds a new file every time I clear cache! And while revisiting previously cached pages seems fine, if I clear the cache and then revisit e.g. the case type settings page, it adds a new file even though the previous one is still there.

Comment: What extensions have you installed?

Comment: Tried it with all extensions disabled - same thing. But now I don't think it's a recent change - see the same thing on 5.13. But I'm sure I've seen a cache clear remove the files at some point.

Comment: Yes a cache clear does remove the files. But with CiviCRM environment setting to production you also need a cache clear in Drupal. (If you are on Drupal).

Comment: @JaapJansma-CiviCooP, Clearing drupal and civicrm cache does not seem to help. I've tried that. I raised this issue on mattermost and Someone mentioned on mattermost that CiviCRM doesn't do any garbage collection of these files currently.

Comment: @Demerit, I am on Civicrm version 5.19. Clearing the cache does not remove the files for me too.

Comment: Clearing drupal cache doesn't work for me either but I think I have a simple PR to propose so that at least the civi clear cache will clear it. Will post back here.

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/1395